# find-file-hook when visiting file literally

Tags: hooks, find-file

I'm trying to hook into `find-file-literally` to turn off some global minor modes when visiting a file literally (which I usually do for large files).

However, it does not appear that `find-file-hook` is run when vising a file literally. The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Visiting-Functions.html#Visiting-Functions) does not mention this, so I'm wondering if this is expected behavior. In any case, what's another way to accomplish the above?

I'm using Emacs 27.1.

Comment: Add an [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions)?

Comment: It *is* intentional, so please `M-x report-emacs-bug` to suggest a documentation improvement.  Details are that `find-file-noselect-1` only calls `after-find-file` if the `rawfile` value is `nil` (i.e. *not* "literally"), and it's `after-find-file` which runs `find-file-hook`.

Comment: @NickD Yes, an advice should work. Thanks!

Comment: Not related to the OP, but 头像很赞！